# ffmpeg - how to check input

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to animate images in a folder, and the result video is going back sometimes to some of the previous images. How to check (print) the sequence of inputs, please?

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*_Roche_potential.png' \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: `-loglevel info/verbose`? Also check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77016/ffmpeg-pattern-type-glob-not-loading-files-in-correct-order

Comment: Thank you very much, ls was the problem